# How to call a SBT task at a scheduled time?

Tags: sbt

When providing a setting value:

```
mySetting := {
   new Thread() {
       override def run() = {
             Thread.sleep(1000)
             // Need to call a task from here
             myTask.value
       }
   }
   "some value"
}
```

I need to call a task after some time.  Of course, in my real scenario, it is something more complex than a simple delay.

I cannot use `myTask.value` because it would perform the task at the wrong time.

How can I call a **task** when I wish to?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call the implementation of the task.

But SBT, isn't aware that the originating task hasn't ended yet, even though it is scheduled for later the 2nd task.